# Compute the similarity rate between two symbols with white background and different angle and position

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to compute the similarity rate between two symbols on a white background. Symbols are black. So only working with "0" and "255" pixels.

The previous method I use is comparing pixel per pixel but there's one problem  with this. It doesn't take account of the angle and the position of the symbols. So two identical symbols can be 100 % different if they have not the same position in the image.

Is there somebody here who knows if a method exits to make this work. I mean to only take account of the difference of symbols themselves. If I want really want to use this method I need to center and rotate the symbols to make a good comparison.

I'd be grateful.

Thank you.

Ask if you need more information :).

Hugo

Comment: how do you define similarity of symbols?

Comment: It can be helpful to share mentioned images.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about OpenCV, but you might want to take a look at [image moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment).
This will probably allow you to center/rotate the symbols to get an optimal (or near optimal) match when comparing pixel-by-pixel.

See [this article](http://raphael.candelier.fr/?blog=Image%20Moments) as well.